# Can you recommend me an Android Book for a Java developer?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone of you recommend a good Android book for developer with java background. I have looked at this book i.e.

1-Programming Android by Zigurd Mednieks, Laird Dornin, G. Blake Meike and Masumi Nakamura

Comment: Did you look at the Android info page?: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reccommend you the [official site](http://developer.android.com/index.html). And if you want to read it offline you can download the documentation using the SDK tool.

[image]

See the 3th item in the list.

And also take a look at [Professional Android 2 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can highly recommend getting a subscription to Mark Murphy's books for one year!

[commonsware](http://commonsware.com/)

Comment: What after an year? Do I have to pay another $45 for next year?

Answer (score 0):

1. Android Recipes
2. Android Wireless Application Development

but I find android's official online documentation and tutorials (dev guide) also very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Since you know java already, the API-demos would be a good start. [link here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've used "Pro Android 3" and although it's not perfect, it's actually been helpful in getting me started. For more advanced problems, I go to the Android dev website or here at stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a practice based approach to learning Android if you already know Java.

If you are using Eclipse then you can create a new project using the Android API demos project. Go to File->New project->Android API Demos

This way you can look at the code as well as make small changes, compile and run the code on a virtual android device. It covers many topics such as fragments, layouts, all the different widgets, etc.

More info below:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

I also used this as a reference when looking for other examples.

http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html